# Place divs side by side

Tags: css, html

I've read through tons of stackoverflow looking for an answer to this question.  Everyone says use `float: left`, `float:right`, `overflow: hidden`, `display: block`, etc. but none of it is working for me.  I'm thinking it has something to do with my margins, but I've been playing around with it and can't find an answer.

I want my Welcome message to display to the left of my two divs.  I'm basically trying to copy the twitter homepage (www.twitter.com).

**Fiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/CuwA6/

**HTML:**

```
<body>          
     <div id="content">
        <div id="welcome">
            <h1>Welcome!</h1>
            <h2>Blah blah blah...</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="login">
        <form>
            <h3>Please Sign In</h3>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Username or Email" /><br/>
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" /><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
        </form>
        </div>

        <div id="signup">
        <form>
            <h3>Sign up</h3>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" /><br/>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><br/>
            <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" /><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="bird">
       <img alt="" src="img/Bird.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: url(img/picture2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#welcome {
    margin: 0 30%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#login, 
#signup {
    margin: 10px 50%;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    padding: 0px 25px 25px 15px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#bird {
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
input {
    margin: 3px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: *sidenote:* 0 has no unit in CSS. no need to add `px` after `0`

Comment: Did you try `display:inline`?

Comment: @RUJordan Yes, on which element were you thinking?

Comment: Well, `<div>` tags are naturally block style, by setting them to inline you override that and they should fall side by side unless your other CSS intervenes with that

Comment: @RUJordan Looks like I need a container around signup and login divs before that will work.  I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try removing the `margin` and adding `float:left` to your welcome message like below:

```
#welcome {
    float:left;
    width: 40%; //added as an edit to the answer based on feedback
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/CuwA6/22/)

**Note:** Removing `margin` is optional. But doing this would make sure part of the text doesn't get hidden under the `login div`.

Comment: How can I prevent text from being hidden under the divs?

Comment: Removing the margin, the text wouldn't get hidden under the divs. Please have a look at my demo fiddle. Or is your margin setting mandatory?

Comment: I want the margin.  I want the elements to be side by side.

Comment: Also, notice the weird behavior that is happening to the right top div when the margin is set?  It looks like it has a huge top padding...

Comment: would it be fine for you to add a width to your welcome message? if no problems, try adding a width (say `width: 40%;`) to it. Check this fiddle [**update**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/CuwA6/22/)

Comment: Yes, I think that will do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Floating the welcome div left will move it to the left of your other divs.

```
#welcome {
    margin: 0 30%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CuwA6/9/)**

Comment: and remove `margin: 0 30%;` to make is fully visible

Comment: If I were to use `margin: 0 40%;` the two divs would cover the text.  How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this issue by creating a new div to contain both sign in/up forms, in effect creating 2 columns/channels for your content (welcome to the left, forms to the right). I've [forked](http://jsfiddle.net/EeVWj/) your original jsFiddle here and have added some ugly background colors to make it clear where each DIV starts and ends. Especially when you're working with otherwise "invisible" DIVs and floats, I find that adding garish background colors often helps me come to grips with where things are landing/beginning/ending.

In this example, I've updated your `#welcome` DIV and added the following, too:

```
#welcome {
    background:green;
    float:left;
    width:35%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle; }
#form-boxes {
    background:orange;
    float:left;
    width:65%; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It does work.  Unfortunately, Harry beat you to it.  +1 for the colors...